# Apply function on all action hooks?

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks, actions

Is there an easy way to apply a function on all action hooks?

> I want to apply `esc_attr()` to every action hook (in a way that would work from functions.php or a plugin).

I figure I would need to filter `do_action` and `do_action_ref_array` except that those functions don't use `apply_filters`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Looks like paranoia. What is underlying aim of this wish?

Comment: If you're worried about a plugin that does not escape data, you should stop using the plugin. No need to use a sledge hammer on the whole operation.

Comment: I want to make a plugin, for which I need action hooks to be escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer the **title**

> Apply function on all action hooks?

isn't that hard, when you know where to look:

```
add_action( 'all', 'callback_function' );
```

Comment: Nice find—and it looks like it also works for filter hooks. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/plugin.php (Ctrl+F for `'all'`)

Answer (score 4):

> I want to make a plugin, for which I need action hooks to be escaped.

**No, your Plugin needs to *escape its own data on output* (and validate/sanitize it on input)**.

Every `add_action()` and `add_filter()` call has an associated *callback function*. You need to do your escaping *inside the callback*.

Answer (score 1):

While this might be possible technically (with messy output buffering) this makes little sense. It would likely break a lot of output and escaping functions **must** be used contextually - there is no sense in using `esc_attr()` for everything.

If this is your own plugin and you have control over code - just go with conventional development techniques like using filters for data that needs to be modified in hooks.